# Computing matrix norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n $ by $n$ symmetric positive  definite matrix with cholesky factorization $A = U^T U $ where $U$ is upper triangular. I want to show that $||A||_2 = ||U||_2^2 $.

Can we show that $||U||_2 = ||U^T||_2 $ ? is this true? If not, what approach can we sue to show this equality?

Comment: Is it the operator norm or the Frobenius norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any $B \in \def\M{\mathop{\rm Mat}}\M_n(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R)$, the 2-norm is given by 
$$ \|B\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(B^t B)} $$
It follows that 
$$ \|U\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(U^t U)} = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A)} $$
and as $A$ is symmetric positive
$$ \|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^t A)} = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^2)} = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A)^2} = \lambda_\max(A) $$
So $\|U\|_2^2 = \|A\|_2$.